# Parent-child attributes in Magento

Tags: magento2

I have car parts products in my M2 store and I need to give my clients availability to filter parts by model of car and year. Each product can be attached to different models/years, in example:

Cabin air filter:

```
Honda Civic - 2016
Honda Civic - 2017
Honda Civic - 2018
Honda Accord - 2013
Honda Accord - 2014
Honda Accord - 2015
Honda Accord - 2016
```

If I would have only models, I could add just simple product attribute. But how should I handle this situation, when I have `"parent"` attribute `(model)` and `"child"` attribute `(year)`?

Comment: you can handle this with configurable products or bundle products.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 doesn't support parent-child product attribute.

Design table as following:

```
Make: ID, Name, Created_At (Honda, Audi, BMW, Ford.. )
Model: ID, Make_ID, Name, Created_At (Civic, Accord, A3, A4 ...)
Year: Make_ID, Model_ID, From, To, Created_At (2015, 2016, 2019...)
```

And use this table to link product with vehicle (Make, Model, Year)

```
Product_Vehicle: ID, Make_ID, Model_ID, Year_ID, Product_ID
```